Adding Problem in Firebase firestore Database?
I added firebase firestore database ,authentication in my project.But when the user signup by new account the It should add default value .But it doesn't add anything in firebase database But authentication details are stored in authentication folder.How to ressolve this problem?This is code  This is problem data doen't add in the database
I want to know how to ressolve the problem?

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

So to understand better, do you expect that once you're authenticated in Firebase, the user details should be written in Firestore? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Unable to understand why your code is not working but try out this
const user = auth.currentUser; this using this in the place of const user = res.user
As auth is already imported and used in code there is no need to import it again.
let me know if its working
